# Download file from iCloud Server

Tags: c#, vb.net, icalendar

The iCloud Server iCalendar file url:

https://p10-calendars.icloud.com/holiday/CN_zh.ics

I can download the file in Browser (it's a text file), but when I try to download with c# or VB, it saved as a small binary file.

I wonder how to download the file correctly like browser.

Thank you for your help.

My code:

```
    Dim wb As New WebClient()
    wb.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/calendar")
    wb.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.33 Safari/537.36")
    wb.DownloadFile("https://p10-calendars.icloud.com/holiday/CN_zh.ics", "C:\\Users\\Johnson\\Desktop\\1.ics")
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the header or any of that... Just download the data and then write it out to disk...

```
 byte[] data = WebClient.DownloadData(URLHERE);

 using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILENAMEWITHEXT, 
 FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
 {
  using(BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
  {
     bw.Write(data);
  }
 }
```

Comment: This works just fine for me, what `specifically does not work`?

Comment: Did you tried this URL? The bytes size is only 4k when I use WebClient.DownloadData method, and the file I downloaded with browser is about 24K.

Comment: Yes I tried it and have proof, it downloads the `ics` file just fine.

Comment: This code will download a 4073 bytes binary file, but a Browser will download a 24439 bytes text file.